# Set active item automatically

Tags: php, menu, yii2, yii2-widget

I have a menu in my app:

```
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/images/logo-top.png', ['id' => 'logo']),
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-static-top',
    ],
]);

if (count($menuItems)) {
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
}
?>

<?php NavBar::end(); ?>
```

`$menuItems` is generated within a Controller:

```
private function constructMenu($categories) {
    $menu = [];

    if (is_array($categories) && (count($categories) > 0)) {
        foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
            $menu[$key] = [
                'label' => $category['name'],
                'url' => Url::to([
                    'category/view',
                    'slug' => $category['slug']
                ]),
            ];
            if (is_array($category['children']) && (count($category['children']) > 0)) {
                $menu[$key]['items'] = $this->constructMenu($category['children']);
            }
        }
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

Also I have urlManager config:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'category/<slug:[\w_-]+>' => 'category/view',
        'item/<slug:[\w_-]+>' => 'item/view',
        'cart/remove/<item_id:\d+>' => 'cart/remove',
        'cart/add/<item_id:\d+>' => 'cart/add',
    ],
],
```

So, the only problem is that the menu items are always `active = false`. How should I modify `constructMenu` method to set proper value for `active` key? Or maybe I should do it within the template?

Here is content of `$menuItems` from PhpStrom debug panel right before it will be passed to `Nav::widget`:

[image: $menuItems variable content]

Here is where I am now:

```
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => Html::img('@web/images/logo-top.png',
        ['id' => 'logo', 'style' => 'height: 40px; filter: invert(100%);']),
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-static-top',
    ],
]);

$controllerAndSlug = $this->context->id . '/' . $this->context->actionParams['slug'];
$menuItems = array_map(
    function($item) use ($controllerAndSlug) {
        $item['active'] = strpos($item['url'], $controllerAndSlug) !== false;
        return $item;
    },
    $menuItems
);

if (count($menuItems)) {
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav'],
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
}
NavBar::end();
```

It works fine, but sets `active` flag only on top level menu items. Now I wonder about how to pass a param to callback-function.

Comment: try adding a trailing slash before the url you are providing `'url' => Url::to([
                    '/category/view',
                    'slug' => $category['slug']
                ]),`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: can you add the `print_r($menuItems)` in your question ? or add a link to pastebin

Comment: added an answer see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private function constructMenu($categories) {
    $menu = [];

    if (is_array($categories) && (count($categories) > 0)) {
        foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
            $menu[$key] = [
                'label' => $category['name'],
                'url' => Url::to([
                    'category/view',
                    'slug' => $category['slug']
                ]),
                'active' => Yii::$app->controller->id == 'category' 
                     && Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'view'
                     && Yii::$app->request->get('slug') == $category['slug']
            ];
            if (is_array($category['children']) && (count($category['children']) > 0)) {
                $menu[$key]['items'] = $this->constructMenu($category['children']);
            }
        }
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... I get the error `Getting unknown property: yii\web\Application::action`

Comment: Sorry, edit it to ```Yii::$app->controller->action```

Answer (score 1):

Although if you provide the full URL with `/controller/action` format it should work if it still does not, then you can use the `active` option of the `item` by checking the current controller, action, and slug

```
protected function constructMenu($categories) {

    $menu = [];
    $controller = Yii::$app->controller->id;
    $action = Yii::$app->controller->action->id;
    $slug = Yii::$app->request->get('slug');

    if( is_array($categories) && (count($categories) > 0) ){
        foreach( $categories as $key => $category ){
            $isActive = ($controller == 'category' && $action == 'view' && $slug == $category['slug']);
            $menu[$key] = [
                'label' => $category['name'],
                'url' => Url::to([
                    'category/view',
                    'slug' => $category['slug']
                ]),
                'active' => $isActive
            ];
            if( is_array($category['children']) && (count($category['children']) > 0) ){
                $menu[$key]['items'] = $this->constructMenu($category['children']);
            }
        }
    }

    return $menu;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Both answers are right, but Thanh Khánh was the first.